# what's the "correct" way to put an EJB in a JPA project?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a simple project built with Eclipse 3.4 (aka IBM RAD) on WebSphere 7.

I have an EAR project, an EJB project, and a JPA project in my workspace.

SHORT VERSION:

An ejb in my EJB project is referencing an EJB in my JPA project, but it gives me an EJBNotFoundException error.

What is the "correct" way of putting an EJB in my JPA project?

## UPDATE

A co-worker tells me the EJBs should be in the EJB project, not the JPA project.  Is that all I did wrong?  Would like a second opinion on this, thanks.

LONG VERSION:

In the JPA project I have my entity/domain objects (ex. Workflow.java) and I have a DAO (ex. WorkflowDAO.java) which is annotated as an EJB with @Stateless.

In the EJB project I have an ejb (ex. WorkflowService.java) which is annotated as an @EJB with @Stateless.

WorkflowService.java references a WorkflowDAO like so:

```
@Stateless
public class WorkflowService /*...*/
  @EJB
  private WorkflowDAO workflowDAO; /*...*
```

The problem is, when I deploy to the server I get the following error:

com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException, EJB with interface test.WorkflowDAO not present in application testEAR.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, I have dug deeper and learned more.  I added a new question that decribes my problem more specifically:

[why can't my EAR project see the annotated EJBs and Entities in my JPA project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436313/why-cant-my-ear-project-see-the-annotated-ejbs-and-entities-in-my-jpa-project)

Comment: So, you considering **this** as an answer to your question? Maybe if this is the answer, you can at least try to explain how you actually **solved** your problem?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem. EJBs in the TestJPA project are still not visible, I had to move them to the TestEJB project. I marked this "answer" as "correct" because the link to the new simplified question is the only path I had to finding a solution to my problem. Your answer (above) didn't help; maybe because your instructions are for Eclipse 3.5 or higher. Like I said in the question, I'm using Eclipse 3.4.

Comment: The point is that you could wait until you find a solution, then post it and accept as an answer. What you just accepted is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to package your `ejb-jar` at the root of `ear` file, and put the `jpa-jar` in the `lib` directory. Usually Eclipse takes care about packaging, when you create `JPA` and `EJB Project` and add them to the separate `Enterprise Java Project`.

**Update**:
As concluded from your comments, you're doing it wrong. You should run `EAR Project`, and have your `JPA` and `EJB` projects added to it. You should check EAR Project properties and ensure that your JPA and EJB projects listed on the `Deployment Assembly` tab. If not, you can add them there. See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing this error in Eclispe, though.  I have not yet built and deployed the EAR file.  Any further ideas or details would help, thanks!

Comment: `I have not yet built and deployed the EAR file` What do you mean? You said, you're getting this exception while trying to deploy it on server, right?

Comment: What I mean is I'm not deploying an EAR file to WebSphere manually.  I'm getting the error while I'm running the app from within the Eclipse IDE (with the WebSphere 7 in the servers list).  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Not really. How exactly are you trying to run it from Eclipse?

Comment: My eclipse workspace has a variety of projects, (EAR, EJB, JPA, Web). To run the app, I right-click on the EJB project, choose Run as > Run on Server > WebSphere 7 -- the server appears to start, but there's a stack trace in the log that indicates the EJBNotFoundException.  Hope that clarifies, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still no luck.  It still says "injection failure" EJBNotFoundException.  By the way, I'm using Eclipse 3.4 (specifically IBM RAD 7.5) and there is no "Deployment Assembly" tab, there's a "Java EE Module Dependencies" tab that appears to do something similar and I ensured all projects are listed an checked.  No luck. <sigh>

Comment: Are you sure, you're trying to run `EAR project`? Maybe try to clean and build all the projects before running it on the server.